# Perfex CRM API - Updating a customer via PUT method not working

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am trying to update customer information on Perfex CRM via their API.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/customers/39',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('company' => 'test'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'authtoken: example'
  ),
));
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The authtoken and customer ID were double-checked.

Tested on Postman and the response is following:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Data Not Acceptable OR Not Provided"
}
```

The API doc for this endpoint can be found [here](https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide/#api-Customer-PutCustomer).

And yes, header `authtoken` is used instead of what they have mentioned `Authorization` in documentation on above link because that is what needs to be used, they have confirmed this (I did try with `Authorization` and the response is `Token is not defined.`)

---

Following is a successfully working example of another one of their endpoints that requires POST method:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api/contacts/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'customer_id' => $userid,
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname,
        'email' => $email,
        'phonenumber' => $phonenumber,
        'password' => $password,
        'is_primary' => 'on',
        'donotsendwelcomeemail' => 'on',
        'permissions' => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
    ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authtoken: example'
    ),
));
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The The API doc for this endpoint can be found [here](https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide/#api-Contact-PostContact).

Comment: The documentation doesn't make it clear at all, but perhaps you're supposed to send the data in JSON format? That's just a guess, but all their examples show responses coming in JSON, so it's logical to assume they want the request data as JSON too - it's worth a try, at least.

Comment: P.S. As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, when you supply a PHP array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data and the data items sent as fields within a multipart request. It seems the server possibly doesn't accept that.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried their other POST endpoints and they all required data in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. But I will give give JSON a try. :)

Comment: `they all required data in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`...yes, you still put the data into that field, but it's the _format_ of the data which is (potentially) significant. But if you're saying that other endpoints work using the exact same approach you've shown above, that does suggest I may not be correct. It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to provide a working example as well, for detailed comparison.

Comment: It does say right in the intro of those docs though that "The Perfex API operates over HTTPS and uses JSON as its data format."

Comment: @ADyson I have added a working example of another endpoint on the same API in my question. And am currently trying to post JSON, will get back with the result. Thanks for help so far. :)

Comment: No problem. Also, to clarify something, when you say "Tested on Postman", are you saying you imported this PHP code into Postman in some way? Or you've created, in postman, what you think is the equivalent request? Or was it the other way round - did postman generate this PHP code for you from a request you generated by hand in the tool?

Comment: @ADyson You were correct, when I posted data as JSON, it worked.
To answer your last query, the code I posted here was generated by Postman.
Let me test the updated code on my server and confirm. Do you want to post an answer and I can select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the intro of those docs it says that

> The Perfex API operates over HTTPS and uses JSON as its data format.

But as per https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, when you supply a PHP array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data` and the data items you supply will be sent as fields within a multipart request.

To send the data as JSON instead, you can do this:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array('company' => 'test')),
```

You may also need to set the Content-Type header appropriately too:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authtoken: example',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
),
```